# [android]Moving activity but the timer still working

Tags: android, timer

I got a problem with my app, I have done a game that use a CountDownTimer.
The timer is doing me some problem when the back button is clicked.

When it is clicked, the app return to the 'main menu activity' but the timer keep going.
When it is done, the "ScoreSend = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PostScoreActivity.class);" Is working and it is bugging all my app.

I have tried to use onDestroy and so but it didn't work aswell,
Also I heard about onBackPressed But I haven't found any information about it.

Anyone knows how to fix it?
Thanks! :)

```
private void incrementAndCheckCounter() {
    if (TimeDone) {
        Intent ScoreSend;
        ScoreSend = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PostScoreActivity.class);
        String ScoreString = String.valueOf(Score);
        ScoreSend.putExtra("FinalScore", ScoreString);
        ScoreSend.putExtra("WhatRank", "Hardcore");


        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);
        int high_score_hardcore = settings.getInt("highscore_hardcore_pref", 0);

        if (Score > high_score_hardcore) {
            ScoreSend.putExtra("HardcoreBig", true);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putInt("highscore_hardcore_pref", Score);
            editor.apply();
        }
        startActivity(ScoreSend);
        finish();
    } else {
        timer.cancel();

        timer = new CountDownTimer(MaxTime[LOST], 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Time.setText((millisUntilFinished / 1000) + " Seconds");


            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                TimeDone = true;
                Time.setText("GAME OVER!");
                incrementAndCheckCounter();
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Call `if(timer!=null)timer.cancel();` before calling `finish();`

Comment: Can you explan me the line? why it will work?

Comment: How do I write the code of onDestroy or any other 'on' cause I really got stuck on it, I haven't understand it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `timer.cancel();` in `onDestroy` or `onStop` of `Activity` which will stop timer when back Button is pressed or `finish` method is called is called in current Activity like:

```
@Override
 protected void onStop() {
  super.onStop();
  if(timer!=null){
    // cancel timer here
     timer.cancel();
   }
}
```

And probably `incrementAndCheckCounter();` method call in `onFinish` is causing issue.

Use a flag to check is current Activity is running or not before calling it again:

```
public boolean isActivityRunning=false;

@Override
 protected void onStart() {
    isActivityRunning=true;
   }
```

and make it false in onStop:

```
@Override
     protected void onStop() {
        isActivityRunning=false;
       }
```

Now check if Activity is running in `onFinish` method of Timer before calling `incrementAndCheckCounter` method like:

```
     @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            TimeDone = true;
            Time.setText("GAME OVER!");
            if(incrementAndCheckCounter)
              incrementAndCheckCounter();
        }
```

Comment: no need to call it just add it in your code and run your app

Comment: @MoShiK: See my edit answer also if still not working